# Eclipse shortcut for search only on page

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

Ctrl+Shift+G allows search in workspace.
But sometimes class is big. Does exist shortcut in Eclipse to receive list of occurrences only in current class or page?
Thanks.

Comment: But Ctrl+F give me one item in time. If page has 1000 lines and item can be 30 times, it is takes many time to find needed occurrence.

Comment: Results must appear in separate page, may be in "Search" - like for Ctrl+Shift+G

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for here?  There are a number of answers and none of them seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Like your images but not for workspace - only for opened in editor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want to see only all methods/variables of current class you always can use **F4** when class "workspace" selected.

**EDIT 1**
Mark you comment. For this you can use **CTRL+H** in "File search" tab set you search criteria and it will display inside "Search" tab all matches for selected class.

**EDIT 2**
If you want use it as fast as CTRL+F command, you need to customize this dialog window. Open it, choose "Customize...", check only "File Search". You can also put into "File name patterns" *****, it allow search on few selected file. After all this manipulations **CTRL+H** command will work like **CTRL+F**.

PS. Use the combination **Ctrl+SHIFT+L**, it will show all available eclipse shortcut with description.

Comment: Yeah, but for this I must made many operation - I asked about shortcut. Shortcuts are needed to do some operation quickly.

Comment: Not so many as you think. You can customize window with shown on CTRL+H and so at it works like CTRL+F command. If you open it, you will see button "Customize ...", if you click on it, in new popup check only "File Search" and save it. After this you can use CTRL+H same as CTRL+F. For me it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Search from the `Search > File` menu option.  That should bring up a dialog similar to:

[image: Eclipse File Search Dialog]

Which should result in something like this:

[image: Eclipse Search Results Window]

Comment: But Ctrl+F give me one item in time. If page has 1000 lines and item can be 30 times, it is takes many time to find needed occurrence.

Comment: Then you can go to the menu option `Search > File`, and specify a specific file (or set of files matching some wildcard) to search within.  I don't believe there's a keyboard shortcut for this, by default, but you can add one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here?  Eclipse allows you to define keyboard shortcuts for pretty much everything (in `Window > Preferences`).  Sure there will be an overhead to set the shortcut, but once it's set, you can always use it.  Or have I not provided you with what you're looking for?

Comment: Did ever try your advice? I tried but search references for page I didn't found possibility.

Comment: Yes, I've used this feature quite a bit.  I'm not certain what you're saying is wrong though.  You should be able to provide a specific file (or pattern, using the `*` and `?` characters as wildcards), and a search query.  Then it will search the file(s) you specified for the term(s) you specified.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: I've updated my answer here to include screenshots of how this should look.  Is there something more than this that you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not useful for me.

Comment: So (just so I can understand what you're asking), the solution I've provided does what you want, with the exception of the fact that you don't want to have to type the name of the file you currently have open?

Comment: Jonathan's answer is good and IMO a better match than the accepted answer which should refer to functionality (as Jonathan's answer does). Users are free to use the default Eclipse key mapping, to unbind the mapping or use something more to their personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the given answers refer to default key mappings. These can be confusing as keyboard mappings may be changed by the user or may differ between versions of Eclipse. Moreover developers new to Eclipse but familiar with other editors such as `Notepad++` or `Visual Studio` will probably want to use familiar mappings for common functionality.

Based on my understanding of what you are asking, the functionality you are looking for can be found under `Windows > Preferences > General > Keys`:

- `Find Next` (double-click the item you are looking for and then use the keyboard shortcut you assign, the default is <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>)
- `Find Previous` (as above, but in the reverse direction, the default is <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + K</kbd>)
- `Open Search Dialog` (you may wish to click `Customize` and then `Remember last used page`, the default is <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>)

In particular, `Find Next` and `Find Previous` search only in the current file.

My own experience with the default Eclipse key mappings has been confusing. For example, why switch the semantics of <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>? Most text editors (`Visual Studio`, `Delphi`, `Notepad`, `Notepad++`, `Word`,  etc) that I have experience with have the following key mappings and you will be more productive in Eclipse if you just re-assign to these:

- `Open Search Dialog` to <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>
- `Find and Replace` to <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>
- `Find Next` to <kbd>F3</kbd>
- `Find Previous` to <kbd>Shift + F3</kbd>

Of course these are suggestions only and purely a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `find` functionality <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> , on selected opened file

Comment: The downvote was uncalled for, but your answer is not quite right. `Ctrl+F` is mapped to `Find and Replace` in Eclipse, not `Find` by default. This is a dumb key mapping...but that is how it is implemented. You may wish to fix or remove your answer.